# Open a text file and transform is to that the first letter is capital and rest is lowercase

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that reads

```
I
BLESS 
THE 
RAINS
DOWN
IN 
AFRICA
```

and I need it to be transformed where all the first letters are capitalized and the rest lowercase. The second part is I need this transformed text to be written into a new text document.

```
text_file = open('lyrics.txt','r')
```

Comment: Does each line only have one word? If there are multiple words per line, should all of their first letters be capitalized, or onlt the first letter of the line?

Comment: One word per line

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`title`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) method on the contents of the file

```
with open("lyrics.txt") as f:
    s = f.read().title()

with open("lyrics.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(s)
```

You could fit this all into one context manager, but I find the above more readable than

```
with open("lyrics.txt", "r+") as f:
    s = f.read().title()
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
   newl = []
   l = f.readlines()
   for i in l:
      newl.append(str(i[0]+i[1:].lower()).strip())
with open('new.txt','w') as f2:
   for i in newl:
      f2.write(i+'\n')
```

Comment: How can I insert it into a newly created text file?

Comment: Is there a way to make the output print on different lines like the original instead of on one line?